# React - intl with external translation file

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to implement language support in the base version of a react app (create using npm create-react etc...)

I've installed react-intl but every time I search on google a guideline, I found a lot of not-working solutions.

What I want is using the classic `<FormattedMessage id="myid" >` in my component. 
Messages are stored in a SEPARATE file called `'./locales/en.json'` or `'./locales/en.js'`.

In my app.js im using

```
import {addLocaleData, IntlProvider} from 'react-intl';
import enLocaleData from 'react-intl/locale-data/en';

addLocaleData(enLocaleData);
```

and I used:

```
<IntlProvider locale='en' messages="i-dont-know-what-insert-here">
  <Index />
</IntlProvider>
```

I've tried a lot of solution.

FIRST APPROACH:
en.json is built like this:

```
{
  "base.user":"Username"
  [...]
}
```

SECOND APPROACH:
en.js is build like this:

```
export const ENGLISH = {
    lang: 'en',
    messages: {
        "base.user":"Username"
      [...]
    }
}
```

These are the example I found on google but I don't know how to use these files inside the app.

As next step, I have to allow the user to change language pressing a flag button but for now, I will happy to see translation files working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I've found a solution so I will post here for others.

FIRST: I've used second approach with lang.js files.
So you have:

```
export const ENGLISH = {
    lang: 'en',
    messages: {
        "base.user":"Username"
      [...]
    }
}
```

In your app.js or in your root.js where you are using IntlProvider, include the files with:

```
import { ENGLISH } from './locales/en';
```

In you app.js (or your root js) use this:

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        locale : 'en',
        messages : ENGLISH.messages
    }

    this.changeLanguage = this.changeLanguage.bind(this);
  }
```

and then:

```
<IntlProvider locale={this.state.locale} messages={this.state.messages}>
    <Index changeLanguage = {this.changeLanguage} />
</IntlProvider>
```

You can see the changeLanguage. That is the second question I post above.
This is the changeLanguage method:

```
changeLanguage(lang)
  {
    switch(lang)
    {
      case "it": this.setState({local:lang}); this.setState({messages:ITALIAN.messages}); break;
      default: this.setState({locale:'en'}); this.setState({messages:ENGLISH.messages}); break;
    }
  }
```

Passing the method to the Index component, allow it to change language using some sort of event.

In your child Component (in my case Index) you have to define a changeLanguage method mapped on father method:

```
changeLanguage = (lang) => {
        this.props.changeLanguage(lang);
    }
```

Finally, if you have a flag button (o something else) you can use:

```
onClick={ () => this.changeLanguage('it') }
```

React will reload component automatically so every

```
<FormattedMessage ...
```

you have, will be translated dinamically